# Transform all text into a cryptic font when someone's behind my back

Tags: windows, android, web-browser, encryption, privacy

I'm tired of the stressing of will someone watch over my back what I'm writing either on PC or on my phone.

I'm looking for a program that transforms all text from a web-browser, application, etc. into a cryptic font that I draw and only I can understand.

This would need to work on my Android phone, USB on any PC. Optionally, I'd like it for J2ME platform and Raspberry Pi's Raspbian OS.

Do you know of any program with these capabilities?

Comment: Are you looking for a piece of software that transforms all text from all programs or just specific programs?

Comment: Any of both that are functional.

Comment: How to detect if someone's behind your back?

Comment: Are you thinking of a one for one character substitution? On the desktop, I would do that with my own CSS and just change font, but I don't know if you can do that on your phone ...

Comment: Otoh, I once spent a few month s in japan and learned katakana, which is fairly simple with only 48 symbols. After that, when had left Japan, I wrote notes in katakana which no one could read. Maybe get a Japansese browser (if there is one which is katakana and not kanji).  At least you coudl take your notes in katakana ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana

Comment: @Thomas I would press a shortcut button combination or maybe keep the cryptic option whenever I know I'm not alone.

Comment: @Mawg I was thinking of replacing the characters, yes, but probably without changing the original website's font. Just that the new font is loaded into the browser and the text re-rendered.

Comment: hmmm, Javascript behind the button to switch CSS (font) on the fly?

Comment: Ah. Yeah. But I hope that doesn't break the site or violate Terms of Service like forbidden hacking/modding/tinkering/altering/anythingthatisfunandthatallthosestupidcopyrightsopapipaactapeopledon'tlike.